# How bad is it if HaveIBeenPwned reports pwned accounts that aren't mine?

Tags: data-breaches

Just for kicks, I recently entered my email in HaveIBeenPwned, figuring that there have been enough data breaches in enough places over the years that it would probably turn up something just by the law of averages.  And I saw something very strange: it reported my email address had been found in a data breach on a site I never signed up for!

How does something like that end up happening, and how seriously should I take it?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but it's mainly because of data sharing between companies. You probably don't need to take it too seriously, since companies don't share stuff like passwords/hashes. But yes, some PII might have been compromised.

Comment: @nobody Good catch!  That exactly answers the question.  For whatever reason, it never showed up as a suggested duplicate when I was typing this up.

Comment: Yeah, site search and dupe suggestions are pretty poor, so I usually check on google